# Sort a list by specific name

Tags: python

I have a list with links like this :

```
my_list = ['google.com', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'fb.com']
```

And I want to sort this list by putting the urls containing the word "wikipedia" first, like this :

```
my_list = ['wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'google.com', 'fb.com']
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is your requirement just that URLs containing `'wikipedia'` in them go first? Are there any other sorting requirements?

Comment: What decides order *after* sorting by URLs containing `'wikipedia'`? For example, can you explain the logic behind ordering `'facebook.com', 'google.com', 'fb.com'`.

Comment: @jpp I think it's like that because of the length `facebook.com` has 12 characters and `google.com` has 10 characters and `fb.com` has 6 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want wikipedia sorted too then

```
my_list = ['google.com', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'fb.com']
list(sorted(my_list, key=lambda e: "00"+e if "wikipedia" in e else e))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_list = ['google.com', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'fb.com']
print(list(reversed(sorted(sorted(my_list,key=lambda x: 'wikipedia' not in x),key=lambda x: len(x)))))
```

Output:

```
['wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'google.com', 'fb.com']
```

Comment: This is not correct output. `wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk` should come before `wikipedia.org/musics` (see OP's desired output).

Comment: @Ajax1234 Edited my answer

Comment: @U8-Forward It's a coincidence this works. Try an url like `'wikipedia.org/Elon'` and it will be incorrectly sorted. Why rely on length? Sorting based on two conditions is usually done with [tuple ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50789220/5079316). Also, do not sort twice. And do not reverse when you can just add a minus sign on your key. I'm sorry, but many things do not work with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort each *kind* of URL (the Wikipedia ones sorted, then the others sorted), you can do this:

```
sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: 'a' + x if 'wikipedia' in x else 'b' + x)
```

That splits the two kinds of URLs: `'a'` for Wikipedia, `'b'` for the others. The `a`s come before the `b`s, and each sub-list is also sorted. The printout is

```
['wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'fb.com', 'google.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it(just to have in mind filter function):

```
my_list = ['google.com', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'fb.com']
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: 'wikipedia' in x, my_list))+list(filter(lambda x: 'wikipedia' not in x, my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tuple` ordering, you can have strings starting with `'wikipedia'` first and then break ties with alphabetical order.

#### Code

```
my_list = ['google.com', 'wikipedia.org/musics',
           'facebook.com', 'wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'fb.com']

new_list = sorted(my_list, key= lambda url: (-url.startswith('wikipedia'), url))
```

#### Output

```
['wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'wikipedia.org/musics', 'facebook.com', 'fb.com', 'google.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['google.com', 'wikipedia.org/musics',
           'facebook.com', 'wikipedia.org/Elon_Musk', 'fb.com']

new_list = sorted(my_list, key= lambda url: (-url.startswith('wikipedia'), url))
```

Comment: Explain how does it solve the issue. Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Comment: Can you please explain, how is this different from answer by @Olivier Melançon?